# Hide or remove image in QML item

Tags: image, qt, qml

I have created a QML entity which includes an image.  I need to hide/remove the image at runtime.  Is there a way to do so from within QML script?

BACKGROUND: I'm creating a world in RUBE, which allows me to associate images with bodies, but not sprites.  I export this to JSON and import into Felgo, where I programatically (in QML) want to replace the static image with a sprite.

Comment: All Items have a “visible” and “opacity” property. Have you tried those?

Comment: If you want to hide the image completely, then you need to set the "visible" property to false (as @JarMan said). From a performance point of view, setting the opacity to 0 to hide the image is not a good idea, because then the image is still rendered (visible disables rendering).

Comment: I need to remove/hide the image only, since I will be adding a sprite.  Changing visibility of the parent will hide my sprite too....

Comment: Then add some code for clarification

Comment: I don't have any code - this was built in RUBE.  I want to add code to remove/hide the image (attached in RUBE) in the QML file

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example with a check box that can toggle the visibility of an Image.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
        visible: true
        width: 600
        height: 400

        ColumnLayout {
                CheckBox {
                        id: checkBox
                        text: qsTr("Show image")
                }

                Image {
                        visible: checkBox.checked
                        source: "qtlogo.png"
                }
        }
}
```